# Why is my callback function not being invoked?

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a function that gets the contents of a load of files and places them in array. I need that array to be referenced in the function that calls the function. I've got a callback in the calling function but it doesn't get invoked.

Any suggestions?
(for purposes of illustration, I have 2 console log calls on the array I need to get back. The 1st is inside my callback which never gets called, and the second is outside it and unsurprisingly shows an empty array.)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path')
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiExpect = chai.expect;
const logger = require('../../../../app/logger/winston');
const pageFolder = 'app/views/pages';

let pages = [];

fdescribe('html pages', function () {
  buildPages(function () {
    console.log(pages);
  });
  console.log(pages)
})

function buildPages() {
  filewalker(pageFolder, function (err, pageList) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    pageList.forEach(function (file) {
      if (!fs.file.isDirectory) {
        fs.readFileSync(file.substring(39), 'utf8', function (err, pageContents) {
          if (err) throw err;
          pages.push({ file: file.substring(39), page: pageContents })
        })
      }
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling the callback function? You are passing a function as the first parameter to `buildPages`, but your `buildPages` function doesn't have any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass and call callback to `buildPages`

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path')
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiExpect = chai.expect;
const logger = require('../../../../app/logger/winston');
const pageFolder = 'app/views/pages';

let pages = [];

fdescribe('html pages', function () {
  buildPages(function () {
    console.log(pages);
  });
  console.log(pages)
})

function buildPages(cb) {
  filewalker(pageFolder, function (err, pageList) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    pageList.forEach(function (file) {
      if (!fs.file.isDirectory) {
        fs.readFileSync(file.substring(39), 'utf8', function (err, pageContents) {
          if (err) throw err;
          pages.push({ file: file.substring(39), page: pageContents })
        })
      }
    })
    cb(); // <--- HERE
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi. I put the callback - cb() - where you suggested and nothing happened. So I moved it a couple of lines down to just before the closing brace. This time the callback got called - so thanks for that. However, pages is showing up as an empty array. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `buildPages` function with a function argument even thought you didn't configure it to accept any argument. That's why the function inside doesn't get called.

Simply add a callback function as an argument in `buildPages` and call that callback function once your done with all the tasks in `buildPages`

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path')
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiExpect = chai.expect;
const logger = require('../../../../app/logger/winston');
const pageFolder = 'app/views/pages';

let pages = [];

fdescribe('html pages', function () {
  buildPages(function () {
    console.log(pages);
  });
  console.log(pages)
})

function buildPages(callback) {
  filewalker(pageFolder, function (err, pageList) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    pageList.forEach(function (file) {
      if (!fs.file.isDirectory) {
        fs.readFileSync(file.substring(39), 'utf8', function (err, pageContents) {
          if (err) throw err;
          pages.push({ file: file.substring(39), page: pageContents })
        })
      }
    })
    callback();
  });
}
```

But i would highly suggest that if you want to get some data from another function. Don't use a global variable as your code will be hard to maintain the more things you add to it, instead pass your data as an argument.

```js
function functionWithResult(callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        var result = [1,2,3,4,5]
        callback(result)
    }, 1000)
}


functionWithResult(function(result) {
    console.log(result)
});
```